# Test java controller using fakeRequest with file on Play Framework 2.2

Tags: java, testing, playframework-2.2

I am trying to test my controller, which receives a *csv* file from a `<form>` as `multipart/form-data`. The submission is coded like this:

```
@form(routes.CsvController.read(),
      'enctype -> "multipart/form-data",
      Symbol("accept-charset") -> "UTF-8") {
  <input type="file" name="csv">
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
}
```

When receiving it in the controller, it works perfectly with the code as follows:

```
package controllers;
import //..
public class CsvController extends Controller {
//..
    public static Result read() {
        MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
        FilePart filePart = body.getFile("csv");
        if (filePart != null) {
            String contentType = filePart.getContentType();
            if (contentType.equals("application/octet-stream") || //ah, windows..
                contentType.equals("text/csv")) {
                File file = filePart.getFile();
                // do stuff with file..
            }
        }
        return TODO;
    }
}
```

When testing the route, however, even though I did manage to feed the file into the request with the code below (using a fakeServer(), but not a fakeRequest()), it has several problems, like hard-coding the URL, and a bug relative to the way it uploads the file, which accepts other file extensions other than *csv*.

This method also passes the test when it should fail (*which can be fixed by adding an additional condition in the controller -- parsing the filePart.getFilename() by it's extension -- but it's rather unacceptable because the fix is only needed for testing*).

```
@Test
public void should_load_file() throws Exception{
    running(testServer(9001), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            File csvFile = new File(FILE_ROOT_PATH+"example.csv");
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
            entity.addPart("csv", new FileBody(csvFile));
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost method = new HttpPost("http://localhost:9001/csv/upload");
            method.setEntity(entity);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(method);
                // assert response..
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this using a *fakeRequest()*? The skeleton would be somewhat like this, as are all of the other tests for this project:

```
@Test
public void should_load_file() {
    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            File csvFile = new File(FILE_ROOT_PATH+"example.csv");
            // how do i create this fake request with my file?? .withBody fails
            /* .withFormUrlEncodedBody also fails cause on 2.2.x it
             * only accepts Map<String, String> */
            FakeRequest fakeRequest = fakeRequest().withBody(csvFile);
            Result result = callAction(CsvController.read(), fakeRequest);
            // assert response..
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There is no treatment for failure because I stripped the code so as to make it more readable.